# event is not defined in FireFox, but ok in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I generate HTML using jQuery:

```
$("<a />")
    .append("demo")
    .click(function () { DemoFunc(event, value.Id) })
```

This works perfect for Chrome and IE8, but in FireFox I got an error: "event is not defined".
I changed the code like this:

```
.attr("onclick", "DemoFunc(event, " + value.Id + ")")
```

It works for Firefox, but not for Chrome and IE.

```
DemoFunc = function (e, assocGroupId) {
    var target = (e.target) ? $(e.target) : $(e.srcElement);
    ....
}
```

Why!? Help!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In IE and Chrome, `event` is resolving to `window.event`. Firefox doesn't have this property and instead provides an event to an event handler function by passing it as a parameter. jQuery abstracts this difference for you by providing an event object parameter in all browsers:

```
$("<a />")
    .append("demo")
    .click(function (evt) { DemoFunc(evt, value.Id) });
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim, a lot! You saved my time! :-)

Comment: In other words.. make sure that 'evt' or whatever you're using in the call also appears in the function() part. Same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

If you have structured your code around working with the original event rather than the jQuery event, you can use `evt.originalEvent` to refer to the native event.