# Using JavaScript / jQuery event handler in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a jQuery function that submits a form via menu navigation functions:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sidebarmenu1 a').on('click', function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#myform').attr('action', url);
        $("#myform").submit();
        if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); } else { event.returnValue = false; }
    })
});
```

This section:

```
if (event.preventDefault) 
{ event.preventDefault(); } 
else 
{ event.returnValue = false; }
```

Prevents the default action of the sidebar button (I think - still new to this) i.e. to simply navigate to a page.

It is written in this way to keep IE happy, because `preventDefault` isn't defined for IE (might be using incorrect terminology there, but IE doesn't like `preventDefault`.)

However now this throws up an error in Firefox, because (as I read on other Stack questions) event is not globally defined for Firefox! I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

Now according to this Stack question:
[event is not defined in FireFox, but ok in Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974601/event-is-not-defined-in-firefox-but-ok-in-chrome-and-ie)

> In IE and Chrome, event is resolving to window.event. Firefox doesn't have this property and instead provides an event to an event handler function by passing it as a parameter. jQuery abstracts this difference for you by providing an event object parameter in all browsers.

But I thought I was using jQuery here and am still getting the issue.

Sorry if I'm making basic mistakes, self teaching myself js and jQ. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do..

```
$(function() {
    $('#sidebarmenu1 a').on('click', function(e) {
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#myform').attr('action', url);
        $("#myform").submit();
        evt.preventDefault();
    })
});​
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. If you have time to explain - what is this? You've defined "e" as either "e" OR a window.event, so then when Firefox examines e.preventDefault(); it tries out "e" (shorthand for event? finds it undefined, but lets it pass because it understands "window.event"?

Comment: e || window.event .. means if e is not defined it will assign it to window.event .. To make things clear I will change the variable in the post.. e works in All the modern browsers, But IE 7 I don't think it works.. So it will use window.event then

Comment: Thank you, I'll read some more about e. Thanks for clarifying your post with the "evt" edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the event object jQuery passes to the event handler you wont have problems

```
$('#sidebarmenu1 a').on('click', function (event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myform').attr('action', url);
    $("#myform").submit();
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had a couple of more points I would up-vote the second answer (passing in the jQuery 'event' argument).

I had unknowingly relied on the global event defined by browsers other than Firefox.  I went back through my code and ensured I was always specifying the event parameter on all click events.

E.g.

```
            $('#situationTextInput')
                .val('')
                .fadeTo(1000, 1.0)
                .focus()
                .off('keydown')
                .on('keydown', function (event) {
                    VsUtils.handleSpanishTextKeydown(event);
                });
```

I've also gotten into the habit of calling .off prior to .on as most of my code is using single pages, reusing content.  Without the .off I was inadvertently stacking up events (even if they were the same callback) in subsequent steps of the dialog.

A side effect of changing my code to pass on 'event' directly to the handler was the binding to 'this.' changed.  I chose to refactor the code to change 'this.' references to 'event.currentTarget.'