# Event parameter not defined for Knockout click binding using Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, knockout.js, click

I am getting this JS error: **ReferenceError: event is not defined** when I try to pass the **event** object to click binding when I use Firefox 23. Everything works fine under Chrome

Here the code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: entries -->
   <tr data-bind="click: function(){ $parent.expandRow($data, event) }">
      ...
   </tr>
<!-- /ko -->


vm.entries.expandRow = function(entry, event){
    ...           
}
```

Comment: Just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974601/event-is-not-defined-in-firefox-but-ok-in-chrome-and-ie probably it is the cause

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here the solution from [github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/752](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/752)

```
<!-- ko foreach: entries -->
   <tr data-bind="click: function(data, event){ $parent.expandRow($data, event) }">
      ...
   </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Under Firefox event is not defined on the window object, instead it needs to be passed to the function.

Comment: In my case passing the event object in the function did not work. I achieved it with `data-bind="click : function(){ $root.clicked(event)}"`. Of course, the knockout version I used is different. It is 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a pretty old question, but still if someone is looking for the answer then I achieved it in the following way:

```
<div id="this-element" data-bind="click : function(){ $root.clicked(event)}">

</div>
```

Following code (clicked function) is written in the ViewModel for the page:

```
this.clicked= function (event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

**Knockout** 3.4.2

**jQuery** 3.2.1